# I need to install composer on my server to be able to perform a cron job with laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, cron, composer-php

Is my first project in laravel and I am trying to perform a cron job but for some reason this does not seem to work, initially I worked the project in local, then upload it to the server and never installed composer in the cPanel, this is the cause that Does not work ?, I leave the code I have used.

for the command

```
<?php 
namespace App\Console\Commands;
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Plan;
use App\Plan_negocio2;
use App\Plan_negocio;
use App\Pagina;
use DateTime;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

//use Illuminate\Foundation\Inspiring;

class Resaltador extends Command {

    /**
     * The console command name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name = 'res:resaltado';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Verificar Resaltador';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $plan=Plan_negocio::all();
        //$fechaAct=$request->fecha;

        if ($plan) 
        {
            $arrNegocio=[];
            foreach ($plan as $key => $value)
             {  
                //$value->fechafin=strtotime("2017-04-07")-time();

            date_default_timezone_set('America/Caracas');   
            $date = new DateTime($value->fechafin);
            $dateHoy=new DateTime();
            //$dat=$dateHoy->getTimestamp();
            $dat=9999999999999999;
            $value->fechafin=$date->getTimestamp();
            //$now = new DateTime();

                //$gene= $date1->format('U') - $now->format('U');


                if ($dat>$value->fechafin) 
                {
                 $negoPlan=Pagina::find($value->negocio_id);
                 $negoPlan->resalta_id=1;
                 $res=$negoPlan->save();

                }

             }
        }

    }

}
```

code of the kernel.php

```
  <?php 
   namespace App\Console;

  use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
  use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

   class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel {
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [

        //'App\Console\Commands\Inspire',
        \App\Console\Commands\Resaltador::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        /*$schedule->command('inspire')
                 ->hourly();*/

                 $schedule->command('res:resaltado')->everyMinute();
    }

}
```

route of the cron job

The path that I give to the cron job does not give me any errors, so I do not think this is giving errors

the path is this

```
/usr/bin/php -q home3/pixsony6/public_html/loupper.com/loupper/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Any suggestions would be good, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need Composer to run a cron job with Laravel.
If you're vendor folder is present with all dependancies then you can run commands.
Composer is for installing packages to the `vendor` folder.
For your specific problem, try using the `php-cli` instead of `php`